# Type args in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this situation in my typescript code:

```
const first = (value: any[]) => {

}
const test = (...args: any[]) => first(...args);
```

In function `test` I pass all params in `first` function. `first(...args)`.

Doing this I get a typescript error: `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.(2556)`.

I notice many answers on this topic but they don't solve my issue.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The error means that you need to use an Array and spread arg within it:**

```
const first = (value: any[]) => {};
const test = (...args: any[]) => first([...args]);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7RgXhgCgG4EMA2ArgKYBcMuYAngNoC6AlOgHwwDeMAvgNwBQokWFGKoMmAHSTcSAOYRylWoxbxk0TDUnjpcxnyA)

Answer (score 2):

Your `first()` function expects to get an array/tuple.
So you can simply pass the array.

```js
const first = (value: any[]) => {};
const test = (...args: any[]) => first(args);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7RgXhgCgG4EMA2ArgKYBcMuYAngNoC6AlOgHwwDeAsAFAwyiQh8xAHT4QAcxwESDANzcAvt36ooxVBkzDtuJOIjlKtRi3jJomXfrnc1FgOS4ARsHsAaGAEYATAyA)

or you can make the `first` method accept variable arguments:

```js
const first = (...value: any[]) => {};
const test = (...args: any[]) => first(...args);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7RgXhgCgHS4G4CGANgK4CmAXDAWAJ4DaAugJToB8MA3gLABQMMUJBBEy2IiADmmQqTLMA3HwC%20fIaihlUGHLgJJJEKjQYt28ZNF3Z9hxX01WA5AQBGwJwBoYARgBMzEA)

Answer (score 1):

Call `first` with `args`

```
const test = (...args: any[]) => first(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript can be used to capture variable number of arguments into an array in a way similar to other C-like languages:

```
function varArgs(...args: any[]) {
  console.log(args.length);
}
```

To pass the array to a function accepting a variable number of arguments, spread syntax can be used:

```
function varArgs(...args: any[]) {
  console.log(...args);
}
```

This approach works just as well with arrow functions:

```
let varArgs = (...args: any[]) => {
  console.log(...args);
}
```

Comment: @empiric, could you take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69391682/use-typescrip-iterfaces-in-react-js-application/69391846#69391846