# Use typescrip iterfaces in react js application

Tags: reactjs

I have a react application where i used typescript.

```js
interface IFirst {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

interface ISecond {
  name: string,
  cars: number,
  friends: number
}

type ICommon = IFirst | ISecond;



const Element: React.FC<ICommon> = ({name, age, cars, friends}) => {
  return <div>Hello {name} {age}, {cars}, {friends}</div>
}

const Parent = () => {
  return <Element name={'J'} age={11}/>
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Element name={'B'} cars={2} friends={6}/>
      <Parent/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I use `Element` component in 2 different components. What i want to achieve is next: If i will use the component in `App` component with `ISecond` interface props then i should't be able to use others props from `IFirst` interface. In my case i should't be able to add `age` prop, and i should get typescrip error. The same logic should be when i use the component in `Parent`, here i should't be able to add props from the `ISecond` interface. I tried to to in my above code but i can't manage, and i get typescript error in `Element` component hovering over `age, cars, friends`. 
 How to to what i describe above? 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-fire-d6dw4?file=/src/App.tsx:229-248

Answer (score 1):

You can't use destructuring of union of interfaces and expect ts to discriminate which interface is the relevant one at runtime.
You also can't use `typeof` or `instanceof` at runtime to dynamically infer it yourself.

What you could do is destructuring all attributes by casting props object to some interface and extract the relevant attributes each time, something like:

```
const Element: React.FC<ICommon> = props => {
  const {name, age} = props as IFirst;
  const {cars, friends} = props as ISecond;
  return (...);
}
```

Please notice that you cannot declare `name` twice in the same scope, so I declared it only once...

If you want to be sure which type you're dealing with, you could determine the 'actual' type without any warnings using casting:

```
if ((props as ISecond).cars !== undefined) {
    const {name, cars, friends} = props as ISecond;
}
```

Same goes with `age` and `IFirst`.

If you want to do a little better practice - there is an article I found about [*Discriminated Unions and Destructuring in TypeScript*](https://kyleshevlin.com/discriminated-unions-and-destructuring-in-typescript).

**Another way** is to 'add' your props object's type the desired attributes using the `is` keyword, while also determining the actual type of your props:

```
function hasCars(obj: any): obj is ISecond {
  return !!obj && typeof obj === "object" && "cars" in obj;
}

function hasAge(obj: any): obj is IFirst {
  return !!obj && typeof obj === "object" && "age" in obj;
}

const Element: React.FC<ICommon> = (props) => {
  if (hasCars(props)) {
    // props is now exactly of type ISecond
    const {name, cars, friends} = props; // This is a valid statement now
    props.friends // Also won't cause the red line...
  }
  else if (hasAge)) {
    // Same here but with IFirst
  }
}
```

Comment: but is there a solution in the case when to use the component with `name` and `age` props, meaning that is used the `IFirst` interface, to hide the typescript suggestion for others props as `cars` and `friends`, so the component should undesratnd that is select only `IFirst` interface`. Is this possible?

Comment: As mentioned in linked article, you'll need an attribute that specify the interface's type so you could infer it at runtime. I don't know of a built-in way to do it.

Comment: You could also check if say `cars` is defined. If so, you're dealing with an `ISecond` object...

Comment: could you show please?

Comment: Could you help?

Comment: Added 2 more methods to achieve the desired outcome

Comment: @ronginat, one more question, is possible in typescript, in the case if i used the component `Element` using the props `name` and `age`. from `IFirst` interface, when i will want to pass `friends` prop also, typescript to throw a warning, like this prop is not from `IFirst` interface. The same idea with `ISecond` interface, to not being able to add `age` prop. Do you know a solution for this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry but if there is a way to achieve this, I don't know it, yet.