# React js select does not show text as value

Tags: reactjs

I am using Chip from "@mui/material/Chip" and Select from "@mui/material/Select"; in my react js application.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import Chip from "@mui/material/Chip";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250
    }
  }
};

const names = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Carl"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Bill"
  }
];

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      personName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium
  };
}

export default function MultipleSelectChip() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([1]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    setPersonName(
      // On autofill we get a the stringified value.
      typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
  };
  console.log(personName, "get a list of ids");
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-chip-label">Chip</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-multiple-chip-label"
          id="demo-multiple-chip"
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput id="select-multiple-chip" label="Chip" />}
          renderValue={(selected) => (
            <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", gap: 0.5 }}>
              {selected.map((value) => (
                <Chip key={value} label={value} />
              ))}
            </Box>
          )}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map(({ id, name }) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={name}
              value={id}
              style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}
            >
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I now if i added as initial value an id, in the dropdown it also show as number, but i need to set there the `name` of the user from the array. Also when i will change the input data in `console.log(personName, "get a list of ids");` i want to see a list of ids, like now. The issue is next: now the dropdown initial value is `1` but it should be `Carl`, because  he has id 1, also when i select `Bill` there appear nr `2`, but i need the text instead the number.
 Who can help with this? 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselectchip-material-demo-forked-lkhzb?file=/demo.js:1264-1309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rendering the `Chip`s this way:

`<Chip key={value} label={names.find(element => element.id === value)?.name} />`

`personName` will remain list of ids but you'll render the relevant names.

Comment: could you also help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69391682/use-typescrip-iterfaces-in-react-js-application